# Cone in three dimension

Tags: 3d

According to me the following statements are true

Statement 1: The guiding curve of a right circular cone is always a circle.

Statement 2: If the guiding curve is a circle  then the cone may or may not be right circular.

Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by "right" circular ? And by "guiding curve" ?

Comment: Guiding curve means the base curve of the cone.

Comment: And "right" circular means "cone of revolution" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Further, it is also true that a cone is right circular if and only if its guiding curve is a circle and its vertex lies on the normal to the base passing through the center of that circle.